# Scrollback not working in terminal window (ssh session)

Tags: linux, terminal, slicehost

I have an ubuntu slice at slicehost, which means it is a DomU on a Xen host - and it's a pretty stripped down installation.

The thing that bugs me is that scrolling back in the terminal using *shift-pgup* doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me **what package enables this scrollback functionality** (so I can check if it is installed) - or if you have any other insights into why it might not be working, let me know.

(note: I am currently running screen with "defscrollback 1024" set, but it still doesn't work)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to `~/.screenrc` log out of screen and back in:

```
shell "/usr/bin/bash"
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

Comment: The second line was all needed. (I am using zsh)

Comment: Same.  The 2nd line is all that's needed.  Can you explain what this does and why it works?

Answer (score 6):

Screen disables the standard scrollback in your local X terminal, because it is actually a curses program behind the scenes.  As Murali said, if you want to use screen's scrollback, you'll need to Ctrl-A esc and then use the regular keys (PgUp/PgDn/cursor) to look through the history.  Escape will get you back out.

Comment: Hmmm.  This is NOT the case on other (Debian) servers that I am running screen on.  I can still use shift-pgup to scroll back on those servers.

Comment: Vi key bindings (hjkl, Ctrl+F, Ctrl+B, / for search etc) will also work in screen's scrollback.

Comment: Oh - also, this is NOT an "X terminal" - it is an ssh session.

Comment: And what is your SSH session running in, perchance?

Answer (score 1):

Is the screen session on your local or remote machine? If it's on the remote, then try going into screen's scroll back mode (Ctrl+A, [ by default).

Does Shift+PgUp work, out of interest?

Comment: My mistake - I meant shift-pgup (not ctrl-pgup).

Comment: +1 Ctrl-A [ does give me scrollback functionality (although not the same as I am used to.)

Comment: Screen's scrollback also allows you to copy and paste between mutliple screen windows. Ctrl-A [ puts you into copy mode; hit space once to set you first mark, space again for the second mark. Then Ctrl-A ] will paste the contents of the buffer into the window you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PuTTY as your terminal, with a screen session running on the server, you must check the box next to "Disable switching to alternate terminal screen" in PuTTY Configuration Terminal->Features. The scroll-back then works as usual.

Comment: I am using gnome-terminal, not PuTTY - but thanks.